# A min function in query set Django to find the earlier date in a model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model that where each entry has a date.  How do I use queryset to find the entry with the earliest date?  This is not dependent on 'pk' because I could add a row with an earlier date at a later time.

This is what I have so far and it doesn't seem to work:

```
Model.objects.get(min(date))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252242/in-django-how-do-i-sort-a-model-on-a-field-and-then-get-the-last-item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252242/in-django-how-do-i-sort-a-model-on-a-field-and-then-get-the-last-item)
and here [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.earliest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.earliest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
earliest = Model.objects.order_by('date')[0]
```

You need to handle the case where there's no objects in `Model` though.

Answer (score 39):

```
Model.objects.earliest('date')
```